# Как сделать iframe frameborder="no" валидным и работающим в IE<9?

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Есть код:

```
<iframe src="iframe.php" frameborder="no" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

При попытке пройти валидацию на http://validator.w3.org/unicorn возникает ошибка:

> The frameborder attribute on the iframe element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.

Гуглю, но пока не смог найти как решить данную проблему. Разумеется рамки не должно быть в IE7,8

Comment: Когда речь идет о кроссбраузерности про валидатор можете забыть.

Comment: Похоже что пока только так:

<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("<iframe src=\"http://адрес\" frameborder=\"0\" style=\"border:none; overflow:hidden; width:500px; height:27px;\"></iframe>");
</script>

Comment: Илья, согласен с Вами. Но это был очередной плевок в душу от IE.

Comment: От того, что вы сгенерируете невалидный html через js, менее невалидным он от этого не станет :)

Если не секрет, скажите, для чего вам сдалась эта валидация?

Comment: Мне интересно насколько валидная верстка способствует индексации и продвижению. Вторая причина - заказчики которые хотят такую верстку. Всё просто.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть более простой способ обмануть валидатор, чем генерировать HTML на js. К примеру, так (конфиг для nginx):

```
if ($http_user_agent ~ W3C) {
    add_header Content-Type text/html;
    return 200 "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Valid HTML</title></head><body>It's valid HTML. Can trust me!</body></html>";
}
```

Comment: А это на каком языке?

Comment: Язык конфига nginx? Это уже совсем шарлатанство, но всеравно спасибо.

Comment: Прошу прощенья, это конфиг для nginx.